# Tailwindcss + Nextjs problems with class + variables

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, classname

Good afternoon, I need help with a big problem I'm having with tailwindcss + nextjs...

So the problem is when it comes to setting the classes, I need to use a variable, the class is set in the css, but the tailwind is not converting the class into a style.

I need it to be like this:

[image]

I already tried to set the class as constant, I tried to set the constant both inside the component and in getstaticprops, and none of them worked.
I've tried to set a class within the css itself and it didn't work either.

Comment: [Don't post code as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tailwind uses regex to find class names, and because of this they need to exist as unbroken strings in your source code. A consequence of this is [you cannot use string interpolation the way you're trying to do](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names), as Tailwind will not be able to find the class name.

What you can do instead is map your props to static class names:

```js
const Component = ({pokemon}) => {
  const pokemonBgVariants = {
    pikachu: 'bg-pokemontype-pikachu',
    bulbasaur: 'bg-pokemontype-bulbasaur',
    // ...
  }

  return (
    <div className=`[...other classes] ${pokemonBgVariants[pokemon.types[0].type.name]}`></div>
  )
}
```